# Hide addon per story in Storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I am building a component library using Storybook with React.
Stories are included using the CSF method.

I have multiple addons, and use them when displaying individual stories.
I am also displaying all stories together in one view, as a reference - it is this story that I want to disable particular addons. In this case, I want to disable Knobs.

When I try to disable individual addons per story, nothing happens.

I have included a simplified version of my `stories.js` file below:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from './button';
import { withKnobs, text } from '@storybook/addon-knobs/react';

// global settings to be exported 
export default {
  title: 'components/Buttons',
  component: Button,
  decorators: [withKnobs],
  parameters: { options: {showPanel: true }}
}

// define individual stories
const Basic = () => <Button className={text("ClassName-Basic", "button basic")} id={text("ID", "Hello-id-basic")} content={text('Content', 'some text for Basic button here')}/>;
const Primary = () => <Button className={text("ClassName-Primary", "button primary")} id={text("ID", "Hello-id-primary")} content={text('Content', 'some text for Primary button here')}/>;
const Secondary = () => <Button className={text("ClassName-Secondary", "button secondary")} id={text("ID", "Hello-id-secondary")} content={text('Content', 'some text for Secondary button here')}/>;
const Disabled = () => <Button className={text("ClassName-Disabled", "button disabled")} id={text("ID", "Hello-id-disabled")} content={text('Content', 'some text for Disabled button here')}/>;
// define all stories together to be displayed in one view
const All = () => <div><Basic /><br /><Primary /><br /><Secondary /><br /><Disabled /></div>;

// export all components individually, and then export them all together
export  {Basic, Primary, Secondary, Disabled, All};

// settings for the 'All' story
All.story = {
  parameters: { 
    options: { 
      withKnobs: {
        disable: true, // do not show the knobs addon on this story
      } 
    }
  }
};
```

Despite adding this setting to disable Knobs on the All story view, it still shows.
What am I doing wrong?

I am using storybook version 5.2.8

Comment: Nevermind, it was as simple as changing ```disable: true``` to ```disabled: true```

Comment: Here is how you can hide controls: `parameters: { controls: { disabled: true } }`

Comment: You can also hide addons panel: `parameters: { options: { showPanel: false } }`

Comment: If you want to hide the addons panel for all stories, write `options: { showPanel: false }` in the parameters variable in **/.storybook/preview.js**