# Disable storybook interactions plugin for specific stories

Tags: storybook, storybook-addon

I'm currently integrating this plugin in our component library:

https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/interactions

Is it possible to disable this plugin via parameters or any sort of configuration?

I have a few stories for which I intend to use the plugin, but not for all. So far, I haven't found any mentions in the docs or in the community about how to achieve this in an easy way.

I used multiple plugins in storybook and they are usually easy to disable with a parameter for example:

Zeplin Addon

```
parameters: {
   zeplinLink: { disable: true },
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680328/hide-addon-per-story-in-storybook) approach?